# Do we need c libraries when running a program?

Tags: c, executable, libraries

The executable file should be in machine code.

So, will make system calls without a need for c libraries.

[image: Generating the executable from source code]

But, I can not figure out what this image means?

[image: C program invoking printf()]

Is it just an abstraction method?

Comment: No, you don't. But they make life much easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a program that calls a library function. In this case, it's the system standard library, also called “the C library” (but there are many other libraries that can be called from C code, this is just a name). “Library function” means that the code of the function is distributed as part of a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)). There are two ways the program can invoke the library function when it runs.

If the library is [linked statically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) into the program, that means that when the program is built, the result is an executable file that includes both the result of compiling program's source code (the `main` function and any other function in the program), and the functions from the library such as `printf` (which the linker finds in a file called `/lib/libc.a` or some similar location¹). This means that the “Linker” step is fully performed when the program is built. All the “(Lib ref)” bits are replaced by code from the library. When the program runs, it doesn't need any library file. The code of `printf` is in the program executable. Since `write` is a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) and not a library function², its code is inside the kernel.

If the library is [linked dynamically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Dynamic_linking), then the linker step in the picture doesn't include the library code in the executable. All it does is fill in some instructions to load certain functions from the library when the program starts: executable still contains “(Lib ref)” bits. When the executable file is executed, one of the first things it does is to load the shared library file (`/lib/libc.so` or some such¹) and match the function names required by the program with the function names offered by the library.

The term “abstraction method” is rather vague. Don't fixate on it. You could say that dynamic linking abstracts the library, since the same executable could be run with different implementations of the library.

The diagram seems to be explaining static linking. In real life, dynamic linking is most common on multiprogramming systems. Static linking has two major downsides: you can't upgrade the library (e.g. to fix a bug) without upgrading all the programs that use it, and if many programs use the same library then you have to store as many copies of the code. Static linking is fine for a low-end embedded system that only runs a single program and can only be upgraded by replacing the whole code image, but dynamic linking is the norm for systems that run many different programs.

¹  <sub>The file names are probably more complex than that on your system, but this is not relevant for this answer.</sub> 
²  <sub>Actually, there's a library function called `write`, but all it does is to make the system call. In my answer I'm referring to the system call by that name.</sub>